# Wamp still open in another program so it wont completely be deleted

Tags: php, mysql, google-chrome, wamp, uninstallation

I am trying to uninstall WAMP completely - wipe every last existence of it from my laptop but it will not let me because I keep having this window pop up:

Folder In Use
The action can not be completed because the folder or a file in it is open in another program
Close the folder or file and try again.

Folder: wamp

---

When I tried other suggestions to uninstall it a window would pop up saying it was in use by chrome - when chrome isn't open and I have cleared all my downloads and any history regarding wamp.

also I cant delete wampmanager.exe because it tells me that the file is open - when I can't find a trace of it anywhere!

Comment: restart the system & delete..

Comment: thank you!  I was googling and researching for a long time. I really appreciate both of you replying so quickly!

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that you have `Stopped all services` using wampmanager.
2. Exit Wampmanager, that the "W" icon that sits in the system tray ( may be in the hidden/overflow part of the system tray )
3. Make sure the `wampapache` and `wampmysqld` or `wampmysqld64` services are stopped. ( Check using the services snapin `services.msc`) If they are not manually STOP them.
4. Uninstall WAMPServer like any other windows program using the `Programs and Features`
5. Once the uninstall is finished, manually delete the `\wamp` folder as it will not remove files that you have added or files that you have changed, like a good install/uninstall